# Debugging kernel panic error

Tags: linux-kernel

I have a arm board on which I am running yocto with kernel 4.1.15. While I am running my python program I get following kernel error frequently but randomly

```
Unable to handle kernel paging request at virtual address 7f101f7c 
pgd = 80004000 
[7f101f7c] *pgd=8c6c4811, *pte=00000000, *ppte=00000000 
Internal error: Oops: 80000007 [#1] PREEMPT SMP ARM 
Modules linked in: wilc3000(O) at_pwr_dev(O) pn5xx_i2c [last unloaded: at_pwr_dev] 
CPU: 0 PID: 1336 Comm: DebugThread Tainted: G O 4.1.15-1.2.0+g77f6154 
Hardware name: Freescale i.MX6 Ultralite (Device Tree) 
task: 8c73b900 ti: 8c8d6000 task.ti: 8c8d6000 
PC is at 0x7f101f7c 
LR is at _raw_spin_unlock_irqrestore+0x28/0x54 
pc : [<7f101f7c>] lr : [<807e1238>] psr: 600f0013 
sp : 8c8d7f30 ip : 00000000 fp : 00000000 
r10: 7f107d30 r9 : 7f107d20 r8 : 7f107f48 
r7 : 00000000 r6 : 8c57b000 r5 : 7f107f48 r4 : 8c54aa00 
r3 : 00000000 r2 : 00000000 r1 : 20000013 r0 : ffffffc2 
Flags: nZCv IRQs on FIQs on Mode SVC_32 ISA ARM Segment kernel 
Control: 10c53c7d Table: 8c52c06a DAC: 00000015 
Process DebugThread (pid: 1336, stack limit = 0x8c8d6210) 
Stack: (0x8c8d7f30 to 0x8c8d8000) 7f20: 8c8063a0 00000000 8c8d6000 00000000 
7f40: 00000000 00000000 00000000 8c975c40 8c54aa00 7f101f28 00000000 00000000 
7f60: 00000000 8004d070 00000000 00000000 7ee95a5c 8c54aa00 00000000 00000000 
7f80: 8c8d7f80 8c8d7f80 00000000 00000000 8c8d7f90 8c8d7f90 8c8d7fac 8c975c40 
7fa0: 8004cf94 00000000 00000000 8000f528 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
7fc0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 
7fe0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000013 00000000 7a9ce301 72611f00 
[<807e1238>] (_raw_spin_unlock_irqrestore) from [<00000000>] ( (null)) 
Code: bad PC value
```

How can I debug this error considering the fact that I don't have access to JTAG on this board. What is the meaning of `Code: bad PC value`? If there any to find anything regarding problem from this log?

Comment: You can try kdump but this may take time. What is placed at address  7f101f7c ? What changes are done to kernel (configs, source code changing)? Are you using non-standard  2:2 va split between user and kernel? Do you constantly hit one address or it changes? The stack trace is the same?

Comment: No the address changes 7f3d1f7c, 7f101f7c, 7f0d4f7c, 7f296f7c, 7f158f7c, 7f647f7c. This kernel error happens when I load some drivers. The error comes randomly. I am using standard kernel provided by NXP. The stack trace is same except for different address.

Comment: The trace looks like you have corrupted register set. I think there is no other way except trying to localize this issue. You said it happens after driver loading. You can move further and try find the exact point.

Answer (score 0):

```
pc : [<7f101f7c>] lr : [<807e1238>] psr: 600f0013
```

In order to translate it into source code line:

```sh
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-addr2line -f -e vmlinux 7f101f7c
```

You must use your `addr2line` command.

Comment: It would be useful to provide a bit more explanation about what this is doing for both the OP as well as subsequent users. Why does this solve the problem? What does the `addr2line` command do? Remember, people reading this don't know how to solve this on their own, so this is a good opportunity to teach them. Do you mind updating your answer with additional explanation and guidance?